# Parse HTML to remove text using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following html in a variable called `Description`:

```
<STYLE>
#productDescription h3 {
margin: 0.75em 0px 0.375em -1px;
}
</STYLE>
</DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=detailBullets class=celwidget data-feature-name="detailBullets">
<STYLE type=text/css>
.detail-bullets-wrapper ul.detail-bullet-list {
margin: 0 0 1px 18px;
}
.detail-bullets-wrapper ul li {
margin-bottom: 5.5px;
}
.detail-bullets-wrapper:last-child {
margin-bottom: 4.5px;
}
</STYLE>

<DIV id=detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div class="a-section feature detail-bullets-wrapper bucket" data-feature-name="detailBullets" data-template-name="detailBullets">
<HR class="a-divider-normal bucketDivider">

<H2>Product details</H2><SPAN class=disclaim></SPAN>
<DIV id=detailBullets_feature_div>
<UL class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical a-spacing-none detail-bullet-list">
<LI><SPAN class=a-list-item><SPAN class=a-text-bold>Department : </SPAN><SPAN>Womens</SPAN> </SPAN></LI>
<LI><SPAN class=a-list-item><SPAN class=a-text-bold>Date First Available : </SPAN><SPAN>May 21, 2018</SPAN> </SPAN></LI>
<LI><SPAN class=a-list-item><SPAN class=a-text-bold>ASIN : </SPAN><SPAN>B07D6WDLLL</SPAN> </SPAN></LI></UL></DIV>
<UL class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical a-spacing-none detail-bullet-list">
<DIV id=dpx-amazon-sales-rank_feature_div>
<DIV id=dpx-amazon-sales-rank_feature_div>
<STYLE type=text/css>
.zg_hrsr_item {list-style : none};
</STYLE>

<LI id=SalesRank style="LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none"><B>Amazon Best Sellers Rank:</B> #2,757,302 in Clothing, Shoes &amp; Jewelry (<A href="about:/gp/bestsellers/fashion/ref=pd_zg_ts_fashion">See Top 100 in Clothing, Shoes &amp; Jewelry</A>) 
<STYLE type=text/css>.zg_hrsr { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }.zg_hrsr_item { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }.zg_hrsr_rank { display: inline-block; width: 80px; text-align: right; }</STYLE>

<UL class=zg_hrsr>
<LI class=zg_hrsr_item><SPAN class=zg_hrsr_rank>#1198384</SPAN> <SPAN class=zg_hrsr_ladder>in&nbsp;<A href="about:/gp/bestsellers/fashion/7581668011/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_fashion">Women's Shops</A></SPAN> </LI>
<LI class=zg_hrsr_item><SPAN class=zg_hrsr_rank>#262103</SPAN> <SPAN class=zg_hrsr_ladder>in&nbsp;<A href="about:/gp/bestsellers/fashion/9056923011/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_fashion">Women's Novelty T-Shirts</A></SPAN> </LI></UL></LI></DIV></DIV></UL>
<UL class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-vertical a-spacing-none detail-bullet-list">
<LI><SPAN class=a-list-item><SPAN class=a-text-bold>Customer Reviews: </SPAN>
<STYLE type=text/css>
/*
* Fix for UDP-1061. Average customer reviews has a small extra line on hover
* https://omni-grok.amazon.com/xref/src/appgroup/websiteTemplates/retail/SoftlinesDetailPageAssets/udp-intl-lock/src/legacy.cssindexName=WebsiteTemplates#40
*/
.noUnderline a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}
</STYLE>

<DIV id=detailBullets_averageCustomerReviews data-ref="dpx_acr_pop_" data-asin="B07D6VPP5K"><SPAN class=a-declarative data-action="acrStarsLink-click-metrics" data-acrStarsLink-click-metrics="{}"><SPAN id=acrPopover title="5.0 out of 5 stars" class="reviewCountTextLinkedHistogram noUnderline"><SPAN class=a-declarative data-action="a-popover" data-a-popover='{"max-width":"700","closeButton":"false","position":"triggerBottom","url":"/gp/customer-reviews/widgets/average-customer-review/popover/ref=dpx_acr_pop_contextId=dpx&amp;asin=B07D6VPP5K"}'><A class="a-popover-trigger a-declarative" href="javascript:void(0)"><I class="a-icon a-icon-star a-star-5"><SPAN class=a-icon-alt>5.0 out of 5 stars</SPAN></I> <I class="a-icon a-icon-popover"></I></A></SPAN><SPAN class=a-letter-space></SPAN></SPAN></SPAN><SPAN class=a-letter-space></SPAN><SPAN class=a-declarative data-action="acrLink-click-metrics" data-acrLink-click-metrics="{}"><A id=acrCustomerReviewLink class=a-link-normal href="about:blank#customerReviews"><SPAN id=acrCustomerReviewText class=a-size-base>3 ratings</SPAN> </A></SPAN>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
P.when('A', 'ready').execute(function(A) {
A.declarative('acrLink-click-metrics', 'click', { "allowLinkDefault" : true }, function(event){
if(window.ue) {
ue.count("acrLinkClickCount", (ue.count("acrLinkClickCount") || 0) + 1);
}
});
});
</SCRIPT>

<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
P.when('A', 'cf').execute(function(A) {
A.declarative('acrStarsLink-click-metrics', 'click', { "allowLinkDefault" : true },  function(event){
if(window.ue) {
ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickCount", (ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickCount") || 0) + 1);
}
});
});
</SCRIPT>
</DIV></SPAN></LI></UL>
<DIV class=a-row></DIV>
<DIV class=a-row></DIV></DIV></DIV>
<DIV id=cpsiaProductSafetyWarning_feature_div class=celwidget data-feature-name="cpsiaProductSafetyWarning"></DIV><br/>
```

which appears as following in html viewer:
[image]

I need to remove the line

```
Amazon Best Sellers Rank: #2,757,302 in Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry (See Top 100 in Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry)
#1198384 in Women's Shops
#262103 in Women's Novelty T-Shirts
```

I am looking to remove all text after "Amazon Best Sellers Rank" to get the following.

[image]

I am not sure how to proceed with this.

Edit:

My skill set is limited to finding the location of first occurence of "Amazon Best Seller Rank" as follows

```
InStr(Description, "Amazon Best Seller Rank")
```

Which I can use to delete the rest of text after finding location of "Amazon Best Seller Rank" but it messes up the html.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far in your question, and explain the problem you ran into. Without that, it seems you are just hoping for someone else to write all the code for you.

Comment: Look up html parser for vba either through ie.document or MSHTML.HTMLDocument | late bound htmlFile;  Also, depends whether you want a string or an altered HTMLDocument at the end. I would start with an html parser and note you can remove nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It's challenging to confirm this answer works because your sample HTML is not valid. Perhaps you did not paste all of it.

But I believe the follwoing VBA function will accomplish what you want:

```
Function ParseYourHTML$(ByVal description$)
    Dim p1&, p2&
    Const P1Marker = "<LI id=SalesRank style="
    Const P2Marker = "</DIV></SPAN></LI></UL>"
    If Len(description) Then
        p1 = InStr(description, P1Marker)
        p2 = InStr(p1, description, P2Marker)
        If p1 Then
            If p2 Then
                ParseYourHTML= Left(description, p1 - 1)
                ParseYourHTML= ParseYourHTML& Mid(description, p2)
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

You can call this function like so:

```
sHTML = ParseHTML(description)
```

After executing the above line, `sHTML` should be assigned the parsed result you seek.

Comment: Did this dolution work for you?